# Dynamics CRM 2011 and MVC application on same hostname/port in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, dynamics-crm-2011, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Window Server 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5. This server hosts a Dynamics CRM 2011 deployment on the default port 80. So, when accessing this website remotely, I'd go to e.g. `http://my.domain.com` and be redirected to `http://my.domain.com/MyOrganization/main.aspx`

I have an MVC 4 web application too, running in a different app pool on the same IIS instance. I'd like to be able to reach this application on the same port and hostname, but using a distinct sub-path such as `http://my.domain.com/SomeCustomPath/`

How do I configure IIS (and/or CRM if necessary) to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really bad idea! I don't know how to accomplish what you are asking off the top of my head, but I do know that it would be completely unsupported by Microsoft. You also open yourself up to possible upgrade issues if Update Rollups update IIS settings and handlers.  This solution is also not portable - if you ever decide to go with CRM Online, this would obviously not be possible. And finally, when something breaks, *AND SOMETHING ALWAYS BREAKS*, you'll always have this weird unsupported customization nagging in the back of your head (are we sure that custom handler or mapping has nothing to do with this problem?).

Why not just use another subdomain? Have your DNS guys set up http://yourapp.domain.com and host your MVC app there. You will retain complete support from Microsoft, not worry about upgrades, and if you ever do move to CRM Online you don't need to change anything!

Comment: There are ways to do this using IIS Rewrite or by placing the application in the CRM site. But @Josh is correct that you shouldn't. It will get real messy and cause significant issues at some point. I understand the desire to just have a single domain name but better to have my.domain.com and myother.domain.com.

Comment: Currently the dev environment is hosted in Azure, so it's not immediately possible to set up subdomains for the provided *.cloudapp.net one, which is why I wanted to explore this option. But I'll accept that it's a bad idea for the reasons you mentioned, and look into other less horrible ways to accomplish it. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I actually have some experience setting up custom domains on Azure websites, so I know it is possible by putting a CNAME entry in your DNS. I don't think you can have custom domains with the "free" website tier though...Thanks for the accept!